# how to add multiple key value pairs to dictionary Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

okay, i'm trying to have the user add a key and value pair to a dictionary i created and have it show up in a table view. i do that just fine but i cant seem to figure out how to add another pair. when i go to add another it replaces the last one. id really like to have multiple pairs. can someone help please?

heres my code:

```
//declaring the dictionary
var cart = [String:String]() 

//attempting to add to dictionary
cart[pizzaNameLabel.text!] = formatter.stringFromNumber(total)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is how [dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) works:

> In computer science, an associative array, map, symbol table, or
>   dictionary is an abstract data type composed of a collection of (key,
>   value) pairs, such that each possible key appears at most once in the
>   collection.

So

```
var cart = [String:String]() 
cart["key"] = "one"
cart["key"] = "two"
print(cart)
```

will print only "key" - "two" part. It seems that you may need an array of tuples instead:

```
var cart = [(String, String)]() 
cart.append(("key", "one"))
cart.append(("key", "two"))
print(cart)
```

will print both pairs.

Answer (score 0):

From Swift 5.0, you can use `KeyValuePairs` like ordered dictionary type with multiple keys.
See this [Apple Document of KeyValuePairs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyvaluepairs). ;)

```
let recordTimes: KeyValuePairs = ["Florence Griffith-Joyner": 10.49,
                                      "Evelyn Ashford": 10.76,
                                      "Evelyn Ashford": 10.79,
                                      "Marlies Gohr": 10.81]
print(recordTimes.first!)
```